# Reflection: How to find a constructor that takes a list of objects?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class that takes a List in the constructor;

```
public class MyClass {

       private List<Structure> structures;

       public MyClass(List<Structure> structures) {
          this.structures = structures;
       }
}
```

that I need to instantiate via reflection. How do I define the call to class.getConstructor() to find this?

Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
Constructor<MyClass> constructor = MyClass.class.getConstructor(List.class);
```

or

```
Constructor constructor = MyClass.class.getConstructor(new Class[]{List.class});
```

for Java 1.4.x or less

Comment: That easy? I was assuming that I had to qualify the list with a reference to the structure - something like List.class<Structure.class> and was going nowhere.

Comment: @user497087 - already thought, that this was your concern - the generic types are erased during compilation, the constructor signature only includes the class name (`java.util.List`) and no generic type (that's why overloading doesn't work if you just use the same types with different generic types)

Answer (score 6):

You can find it just by passing in `List.class`. For example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> clazz = MyClass.class;
        Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(List.class);

        ctor.newInstance(new Object[] { null });
    }
}
```

If you need to validate the generic parameter types, you can use [`getGenericParameterTypes`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#getGenericParameterTypes%28%29) and examine the `Type[]` which it returns. For example:

```
Type[] types = ctor.getGenericParameterTypes();
System.out.println(types[0]); // Prints java.util.List<Structure>
```

You don't need to specify the type argument when you call `getConstructor` because you can't overload the constructor by using parameters with *just* different type parameters. Those parameter types would have the same *type erasure*. For example, if you try to add another constructor with this signature:

```
public MyClass(List<String> structures)
```

you'll get an error like this:

> MyClass.java:7: name clash: `MyClass(java.util.List<java.lang.String>)` and
>   `MyClass(java.util.List<Structure>)` have the same erasure